# Expo MediaLibrary ios smart albums not returning

Tags: expo, media-library

i try to het all album names via EXPO MediaLibrary, however MediaLibrary.getAlbumsAsync() only returns user created albums. Can anyone please suggest how you handled this situation and get ios smart albums as well? Thanks for your support and guidence.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but for the benefit of anyone else who may find this helpful, the solution here is to pass in as parameters the option to include smart albums in the search. This is how you do it:

```
const getAlbums = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumsAsync({includeSmartAlbums: true})
```

This will return an array of objects representing the albums, including Recents album.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const isRecent = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync('Recent')

if (isRecent) {
    console.log('exist')
} else {
    const allPhotos = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync()
    const recentAlbum = await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('Recent', {}) 
    await MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync(allPhotos.assets, recentAlbum)             
}
```

I can't get smart album too. I try to create a copy one.

but I  thought this is not a efficiency way.